# Taking list entry and displaying in another form?

Tags: c#

I have a list and i have a item selected that holds 3 entry ( name, email, and phone number) i want to take those and display them in another form that that has three text box's. how to i take the selected item and get it to display that content on another form.

```
public partial class EmailAddressBook : Form
{
    public EmailAddressBook()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Closes the application 

        Application.Exit();


    }

    public List<EmailInfo> emailList = new List<EmailInfo>();

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Activates AddNewNames form for use 
        frmAddNewName frmNames = new frmAddNewName();
        //Shows the AddNewNames Form
        frmNames.ShowDialog();
        //Adds to the list
        lstNames.Items.Add(frmNames.objEmail.Name);

    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clears selected iteam from the listbox.

        if (this.lstNames.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            this.lstNames.Items.RemoveAt(this.lstNames.SelectedIndex);
        else MessageBox.Show("Please select name to delete.", "Selection Error");


    }

    private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Displays the contact information



    }
```

Comment: How you hold those entries? What have you tried? What type of list?

Comment: i have a collection. and i haven't tried anything cant find anything on how to do it

Comment: You should post at least some piece of code to have a reference on what you are doing and how you are doing it. You're information is very vague

Comment: just edited it with the code. i also have a class but this is the main form code.

Comment: but i have that part working how do i take what i have already stored in the item in the list and then display it back into the frmAddNewNames.

Answer (score 2):

You should take your `frmAddNewName`, and add a property to hold the list

```
public List<InsertTypeHere> MyList{get; set;}
```

and then when you declare your form, just populate that property

```
    frmAddNewName frmNames = new frmAddNewName();
    frmNames.MyList = myList;
    //Shows the AddNewNames Form
    frmNames.ShowDialog();
```

Or, you can pass it into the constructor(you'll have to modify the constructor.)

```
    frmAddNewName frmNames = new frmAddNewName(myList);
    //Shows the AddNewNames Form
    frmNames.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score -1):

Static variables will be option that will work.